# complex mongodb count query

Tags: mongodb, count

The below document is an example of the documents contained in a collection. The value of the "when" key may take on the values "manual" (which it does in the example below), "upon_posting", and "periodic".

Does anyone know how to write a query that will count how many documents in this collection satisfy the following condition: not all of the values of the "when" key are identical to each other within the document. I.e. "billing.daily_nonzero.when" = "manual", but "billing.daily_zero.when" = "periodic"?

(To clarify, the document below is an example of a document that does *not* satisfy the above condition, since all of the values for the "when" key in the various subobjects are all identical, and equal to "manual").

```
{
"billing" : {
    "daily_nonzero" : [
        {
            "when" : "manual",
            "mode" : "email",
            "tpl" : "std",
            "email" : [
                "helen.zelan@navhms.com"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "daily_zero" : [
        {
            "when" : "manual",
            "mode" : "email",
            "tpl" : "std",
            "email" : [
                "helen.zelan@navhms.com"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ppd" : [
        {
            "when" : "manual",
            "mode" : "email",
            "tpl" : "std",
            "email" : [
                "helen.zelan@navhms.com"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "rtn" : [ ],
    "daily_nonzero_hdr" : [
        {
            "when" : "manual",
            "mode" : "email",
            "tpl" : "std",
            "email" : [
                "helen.zelan@navhms.com"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ent" : [
        {
            "when" : "manual",
            "mode" : "email",
            "tpl" : "std",
            "email" : [
                "helen.zelan@navhms.com"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: each element of the billing document contains an array of sub-documents - does this mean that there could be multiple items in each array so? e.g. instead of just "billing.daily_nonzero.when" - there could be billing.daily_nonzero.0.when and billing.daily_nonzero.1.when etc...

Comment: I beleive your query may be similar this one [How to aggregate fields from embedded documents in Mongoose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28449916/how-to-aggregate-fields-from-embedded-documents-in-mongoose/28474135#28474135), please check it out :)

Comment: Are the keys under `billing` dynamic or fixed? If they are fixed for all your documents, then this is possible with aggregation. Otherwise, it's not.